# How Do I Add This Short Code to Wordpress Title [dyna dynami="cittiess"]?

Tags: wordpress

I am in need little help not knowing what to do this is why am here to get guidiance from you.

I am trying to add my wordpress shortcode to the page title below is the shortcode am using:

```
[dyna dynami="cittiess"]
```

But, it's not working; it shows `[dyna dynami="cittiess"]` rather then spun text.

This short code works in the content area but its not working in the title area kindly tell me what edits I should make as I am new to this please cheers.
Any solutions? Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Short codes does not work in `title` by default. So if you want to enable short codes in title then you need to put this code in your `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
```

Comment: i have added the code add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' );  works on breadcrumb but 1 more problem i se is  were you se the firefox tab when i highlight the tab to read the title i can se the shortcode the rather then generated plain text whats wrong.